# Type bounds constraints restrictions in Higher Kinds when extending a trait

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Let's set up issue conditions

```scala
trait Bound
trait Bound2 extends Bound

trait T1[B <: Bound]
trait T2[B <: Bound2] extends T1[B]

trait WrapperT1[Tz[B2 <: Bound] <: T1[B2]]
```

This code compile without problem, issue comes when trying to extend `WrapperT1`

```scala
trait WrapperT2[Tz[B2 <: Bound2] <: T2[B2]] extends WrapperT1[T2]

// Compilator error
kinds of the type arguments (T2) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type Tz) in trait WrapperT1.

[error] ex.T2's type parameters do not match type Tz's expected parameters:

[error] type B's bounds <: Bound2 are stricter than type B2's declared bounds <: ex.Bound

[error]     trait WrapperT2[Tz[B2 <: Bound2] <: T2[B2]] extends WrapperT1[T2]
```

Yes `B2 <: Bound2` is stricter than `B2 <: Bound` but i'm not understanding why the compilator complains for this reason and i would be grateful to know more about it.

## Potential solution but does it has some drawbacks ?

```scala
trait Bound
trait Bound2 extends Bound

trait T1[B] {
    implicit val ev: B <:< Bound
}

trait T2[B] extends T1[B] {
    // this is possible thank's to covariance of class `<:<[-From, +To]` if i'm not wrong
    implicit val ev: B <:< Bound2
}

trait WrapperT1[Tz[B2] <: T1[B2]]
// Compiles
trait WrapperT2[Tz[B2] <: T2[B2]] extends WrapperT1[Tz]
```

This looks nice and we keep the compilation checks about `B2` generic type but is there any inconveniant using it ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the compiler complains, let's look at this piece of code (which is the same as your code, but with different names)

```
trait Show[A <: AnyRef] {
  def show(a: A): Unit
}
trait ShowString[S <: CharSequence] extends Show[S] {
  def show(s: S): Unit = println(s)
}

trait Wrapper1[S[A <: AnyRef] <: Show[A]] {
  def show[A <: AnyRef](a: A)(implicit show: S[A]): Unit = show.show(a)
}

trait Wrapper2[S[C <: CharSequence] <: ShowString[C]] extends Wrapper1[S]
```

Here, too, the compiler emits the error `type C's bounds <: CharSequence are stricter than type A's declared bounds <: AnyRef`, but let's pretend you somehow get it to compile here. That would mean if someone wanted to use your wrapper class to print, say, a list, they wouldn't be able to do that, meaning that your wrapper class would be basically useless.

```
val w2: Wrapper[ShowString] = ???
w2.show(List(1, 2))
//Error: could not find implicit value for parameter show: ShowString[List[Int]]
```

In this case, it's just that the implicit isn't found. However, if you have a method in wrapper that accepts a `S[_]` (or `Tz[_]`, from your example) and you try to shoehorn an object of the wrong type into your `show` method, you could get a runtime exception.

It fails for the same reason you can't do this

```
trait T1[A] {
  def process(a: A): Unit
}
trait T2 extends T1[Int] {
  def process(i: Int): Unit = ???
}
val t2: T2 = ???

t2.process("not an int")
```

`T2` is just not equipped to handle anything that is not an `Int`, and the same applies here.